# JS draw an arrow pointing from one div to another

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I have the following code:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="air1">Medium 1</div>
  <div class="child" id="glass">Medium 2</div>
  <div class="child" id="air2">Medium 1</div>
</div>

<style>
  #parent {
    background: #999;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  #glass {
    background: #666;
  }
  .child {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

I want to draw an arrow from #air1 into #glass using an svg.  I added the following code into the div to draw an example arrow:

```
<svg width="300" height="100">

    <defs>
        <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
            <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:red;" />
        </marker>
    </defs>

    <path d="M30,150 L100,50"
          style="stroke:red; stroke-width: 1.25px; fill: none;
                 marker-end: url(#arrow);"
    />

</svg>
```

I don't want the arrow pointed in a random direction though, I want it to point into #glass like this: [image]

Also, how would I go about drawing a less steep arrow like this as well:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) (inserting the svg into the first section and set it to `position: absolute;`) and adjusting the offset of the path element. To make the arrow pointing down, just use a negative value for the second value of the path description attribute.

For more information see [w3schools about path](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp).

```css
#parent {
  background: #999;
  padding: 0px;
}
#glass {
  background: #666;
}
.child {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child" id="air1">Medium 1
    <svg width="400" height="200">
      <defs>
        <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refx="2" refy="6" orient="auto">
          <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2" style="fill:red;" />
        </marker>
      </defs>
      <path d="M-600,-10 L300,195" style="stroke:red; stroke-width: 1.25px; fill: none; marker-end: url(#arrow);" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="child" id="glass">Medium 2</div>
  <div class="child" id="air2">Medium 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  What values would I want to adjust if I wanted the arrow to be much less steep like [this](https://imgur.com/a/4lQdU)

Comment: updated the answer. set `left: 0;` for the svg and just play around with the path descriptors, e.g. with the first value you can affect the angle

Comment: Do you mind setting me a guide or documentation on this?  Like I need a way to learn how to do this for multiple arrows at once

Comment: updated the answer with a w3schools page with examples